# git log --name-status HEAD^..HEAD shows previous commit on mac but not Windows?

Tags: python, windows, git

I am doing dev on my mac, but i have a windows VM i end up running some builds off of. Its pretty simple.  I have Jenkins pull and build the application daily.

In this script there are some metadata i need to obtain.  I need to obtain a list of branches on the git server, and if it has it (as the branch may not have commits) the most recent commit's metadata.  Specifically the committers email.

In general on my mac it was something as simple as:

```
git branch --all > branches
for b in $(cat branches);
do
  git checkout $b
  git log --name-status HEAD^..HEAD | grep Author | cut -d"<" -f2 | cut -d">" -f1 > email
  echo $b > branch
  python buildScript.py $(cat email) $(cat branch)
  ; done
rm email branch
mv branches old_branches
```

The issue i noticed is that:

1. On a fresh pull of a branch the `git log --name-status` shows the commits, but *HEAD^..HEAD* was returning no results.
2. grep is not a valid cmd in the windows Cmd Prompt.
3. cut is not a valid cmd in the windows Cmd Prompt.

I can likely find grep and cut alternatives.

can someone explain why commits wont show up on Windows?  Is there a solid built in Python Utility which could handle this all therein?  I have no issues with running straight bash, but i think python can be more clean since i am already running a python script to build...

Edit:
My desired end state is a bash script (or a python script) which would do as follows:

```
loop over all branches.
if branch is new since the last time the script was run, and has at least 1 commit
   run_a_python_script with the committers email and that branch.
else if there were deleted branches since the last time it was run:
   run_another_python_script with the branch
else
   nothing happens because this script already ran once.
```

I have this set on a 10 minute interval cron.

This would easily be done in Python OR Bash.

Comment: If you are using Windows CMD.EXE, note that `^` is a special character there (google search suggests it quotes the next character the way `\ ` does in sh/bash) so that `HEAD^..HEAD` results in Git seeing `HEAD..HEAD`. There's a better way to do all of this though.

Comment: Im going to add a quick desired end state edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a general recipe, implementable in Python via `subprocess.Popen` or in sh / bash in the obvious way.

> ```
> loop over all branches
> ```

Use `git for-each-ref`.  If you are on the server that has the branches, this is `git for-each-ref refs/heads`; if you are on a client that has the branches renamed to remote-tracking names (`origin/master` and so on), this is `git for-each-ref refs/remotes/origin`.  Use the formatting directives of `for-each-ref` to produce the appropriate short name if desired (but note the six-step lookup process in [the gitrevisions documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) and be sure that the short name will look up the appropriate hash—it's generally wiser in scripts to keep the *full* name as long as possible, passing it through to additional scripts that similarly understand this pattern, lest you find the commit hash for a *tag* named `xyz` when there is also a *branch* named `xyz`).

(If you are using a Python library, it probably has an iterator on references that functions similarly to `git for-each-ref`.)

> ```
> if branch is new since the last time the script was run, and has at least 1 commit
> ```

By definition, a Git branch cannot exist without having at least one commit on it.  The reason is that the branch *name* is simply a name for one (1) commit hash ID.

The "is new since last run" requires some sort of memory, of course.

> ```
>    run_a_python_script with the committers email and that branch.
> ```

Given a reference name `$ref`, to find the email for the author (which is what you are doing in the original code):

```
git log --no-walk --pretty=format:%ae $ref
```

To find the email for the committer—note that each commit has a separate "author" and "committer", though the two are typically the same in most cases—use `%ce` instead of `%ae`.

If the reference has the form `refs/heads/name`, the branch is named *`name`*; if it has the form `refs/remotes/origin/name`, the branch is named *`name`*.  The `%(refname:short)` format in `git for-each-ref` will strip off the `refs/heads/` or `refs/remotes/` part, but as noted earlier, that might be unwise to do too early.  If the Python script can handle the full reference name, that would be best.

> ```
> else if there were deleted branches since the last time it was run:
> ```

This also requires memory, and some way of doing set subtraction (saved reference set minus current reference set equals deleted set).  Memory in shell scripts means an external file; memory in Python code could also be an external file, using `pickle` or JSon formatting or whatever.

> ```
>   run_another_python_script with the branch
> else
>    nothing happens because this script already ran once.
> ```

Comment: Agree, I was thinking to maintain over the course of time,1 file to maintain previous information over iterations.The only thing I can think of is that when using BitBucket for example to create a new branch, I looked at the branch and the previous commit would actually be from the trunk the branch came off of. Is there a way to say get the person who created that Branch in Bitbucket OR wait until there at least 1 dedicated commit to it? Ideally, the code I am working with runs scripts based on the branch, but emails the contributor to it. (Each branch has 1 owner for my team).

Comment: Git itself does not attach any meaning to branch names (they merely identify that one single commit that they identify), so anything you do here is going to be purely your own construction. You can therefore do anything you want—but making your users conform to your constraints may prove difficult. :-) Note that if you update your own clone based on some version you treat as the Source of Truth (e.g., the one on Bitbucket), you can always detect added commits and removed commits, but you cannot necessarily tell *who* added and removed them, you can only look at the contents.

Comment: Anyone can push anyone else's commits, or commit while claiming to be someone else, so the contents themselves are not in general something you can trust. This takes you right back to "making your users conform to your constraints". If you control the *server* that provides this Source of Truth, however, you can control who can push *to* the server, and do whatever verification you like at that time.

Comment: ahhh, ok.  I think since we all have git configured with our names and emails, the respective machine will append it to the commit, one would think.  That is how we are determining ownership.  While Anyone CAN commit to that branch, we pretty much use them as silo'd development for a task.  A task just happens to have a 1-1 relationship with a developer.   So as long as the branch is created, the first commit created therein would then be the owner.  It seems though that when creating a branch say, off of master, until a commit it done to that branch the it still points to that one commit

Comment: Yes i understand the previous commit in that regard still belongs to that branch, but i was thinking of like: the point in which the branch becomes like +1 ahead of master.    Does that make sense?  Is that possible?

Comment: Well, consider that I can do: `git push origin <hash>:branch` to create the name `branch` on the server at `origin`, pointing to any arbitrary existing commit by its hash ID. If the name already exists, I can do `git push -f origin <hash>:branch` to *change* it arbitrarily, to point to any existing commit by hash ID. So your assumption that branch names appear, pointing to some existing commit reachable from the tip of `master`, and then move forward, isn't necessarily the case!

Comment: What you *can* do is to detect whether the commit to which some name points right  now is also reachable from `master`—and, by keeping a memory of which branch-names existed before and which commits were reachable from those branch-tip commits before, you can observe whether the branch name has moved in a "forwards" fashion, or a "backwards" one (force push to remove commits), or both at the same time. What you don't know is what happened *in between* your two observations, if anything actually happened between them.